# remove half installed software

Tags: desktop-environments

I wanted install kDE plasma desktop
first I entered

```
$ sudo apt install tasksel
```

then

```
$ sudo apt install sddm
```

it stopped saying couldn't fetch some archive files etc;
now I want to remove the files downloaded during this process as they are no longer useful to me

Comment: `sudo apt purge sddm tasksel ; sudo apt autoremove`  (the `sddm` may not be needed if it didn't install; the autoremove will remove any dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt purge tasksel sddm`

will remove (including configuration files) tasksel & sddm packages.  You may not need to purge/remove sddm if it was not installed.

`sudo apt autoremove`

will remove any unwanted dependencies that are no longer needed; ie. anything pulled in when you installed tasksel sddm or any other packages you have removed.

Comment: Please feel free to accept the answer.